# Вопрос по javac и package

Tags: java, cmd, javac

У меня есть некий java файл, в нем прописан package - допустим package com.ya.tut.sprytalsy.

Вопрос: можете подсказать какой флаг указать в cmd (javac -флаг), чтобы он после компиляции не смотрел на package, т.е. я смог бы выполнить java filename.

Пробовал -sourcepath, не пошло(может не так пробовал). 
Пробовал -classpath - Но так понял что он дает ссылку на "исходник".

Comment: А в чём проблема собрать JAR и запускать через `java -jar somefile.jar`?

Comment: @AlexChermenin, думаю проблем нет, но для этого надо собрать jar. Думаю что все такие есть шаги позволяющие сразу увидеть результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы скомпилировать 1 файл без указания пакета, вам надо в cmd перейти в папку, где и лежит этот java файл.

Вызвать `javac fileName.java`

Файл скомпилируется

Потом не выходя из папки вызвать `java fileName`

---

-classpath указывает компилятору на готовые class файлы, который используются в вашем проекте, они называются зависимостями и для простой и удобной работы с ними лучше использовать систему сборки.

---

Флаг -sourcepathиспользуется если у вас несколько классов в разных пакетах и все они используются классом, который вы хотите отправить на компиляцию.

Есть классы

```
src.com.java.A
src.com.util.B
src.com.util.V
```

A класс использует в своей работе B и V, значит для компиляции А надо компилировать все 3 класса

находясь в директории `src/com/java` можно вызвать команду

```
javac -sourcepath ../util A.java
```

лучше конечно компилировать из корня проекта, тогда команда немного поменяется ( находиться надо на уровне src)

```
javac -sourcepath com com/java/A.java
```

---

Чтобы ваши class файлы не валялись где попало, можно указать ключ -d ч указанием папки куда положить class фалы. Только надо сначала ручками создать папку для классов, назвать можно как угодно, я назову `classes`

```
javac -d classes -sourcepath com com/java/A.java
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Т.е. мне как минимум надо создать фейк папки все таки? - Я об этом думал, но нельзя в javac - сделать так чтобы он при компиляции не смотрел на строки - в моем случаи на строки package?

Comment: @sank Не могу нормально сформулировать, надеюсь поймете. Package в имени класса это и есть дерево папок. Создав класс com.ya.tut.sprytalsy.A ваш java файл будет лежать по адресу ../com/ya/tut/sprytalsy/A.java. Когда вы компилируете файл вам надо указать относительный путь к нему (относительно папки где вы находитесь).

Comment: да, понял. Но вот интересно, можно ли уйти от строки package).

Comment: @sank да можно если у вас весь проект это 1 класс. Пакеты входят в имя класса. В проекте может быть несколько классов с одним именем, но в разных пакетах. Скажем так, если у вас есть 1 друг по имени Дима, то вы можете говорить про него "Дима", но если Дим в вашей компании 10, то использовать ФамилияИмя. Если из 10 Дим 5 однофамильцев, придется использовать ОтчествоФамилияИмя. Если и отчества одинаковые, то можно добавить прозвище прозвищеОтчествоФамилияИмя. Это все нужно, чтобы вы могли обратиться к конкретному человеку.

Comment: Если компилятор не поймет к какому классу обращаться, он не будет переспрашивать, просто кинет ошибку и разбирайтесь сами. Либо (ещё хуже) решит сам какой класс вам использовать. Вы звали "Диму сторожа", а пришел "Дима водитель"

Comment: "можно если у вас весь проект это 1 класс" - можно и даже если больше одного класса, просто все классы будут лежать в одной папке и их даже не нужно будет импортировать. Но для большого кол-ва классов это сильно не рекомендуется.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вам просто нужно удалить package совсем и хранить все классы в одной папке, тогда можно будет собирать без всяких package (будет считаться, что у вас одни пустой package на весь проект), но это для мало-мальских больших проектов это не очень хорошое решение.